# Multi state model in MVI pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns

I understand that the advantage of the MVI pattern is that it is a single-state flow. So is it really necessary to have only one state model in MVI?

My app has several activities, and the subject of data obtained for each activity is completely different. For example, activity A gets the dog's information, and activity B gets the information of a Github user. In this case, if MVI-pattern should be only one state model, the mvi state model contains all the data information of activities A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases we're talking about single-state per ViewModel. And ViewModel is (usually, but not always) bound to a single screen. There is absolutely no incentive to store whole application state in a single object, that would get out of hand really quick

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, Mvi is one of the presentation patterns, which addresses and try to solve the presentation problems. so by presentation we mean Single Screen whether it's an Activity, Fragment or Ui controller.

So with screen A, you'll have uni directional flow to get the Dog's information, and another one to Screen B, and so on.